# Sonar about org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders.get()

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube

Sonar reports an Error on `org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders.get()`. The following code:

```
1. MessageHeaders foo = new MessageHeaders(Collections.emptyMap());
2. String bar = foo.get("foobar", String.class);
3. if (bar != null) {
4.     return bar
5. }
6. ...
```

Sonar tells about line 3: "Remove this expression which always evaluates to "true".

Am I wrong when thinking this is an incorrect analysis by Sonar?
What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you provide your SonarJava version? It seems to be a known issue fixed by https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2864 in SonarJava 5.7

Comment: Version 6.7 (build 33306) is the version of SonarQube UI (not sure what's beneath)

Comment: If you are not SonarQube admin, you can still access to the `/api/plugins/installed` url. Then find `sonar-java-plugin` to get the version number. For example on SonarCloud, using [this url](https://sonarcloud.io/api/plugins/installed), you can see that the current version of SonarJava is 5.7.0.15470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to method definition

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Nullable
public <T> T get(Object key, Class<T> type) {
    Object value = this.headers.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!type.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect type specified for header '" +
                key + "'. Expected [" + type + "] but actual type is [" + value.getClass() + "]");
    }
    return (T) value;
}
```

at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/MessageHeaders.java

you can flag sonar error as false positive because it may return null.

Comment: So, you say I am right in my conclusion? Where should I flag this error?

Comment: Yes, i think sonar gave false positive. You can find useful explanations about flagging sonar issue as false positive on stackoverflow. If you accept this answer please mark as answer.